# Spliting a window into two panes. Left pane should be fixed

Tags: mfc

In MFC, I am trying to split a window into two panes. I need left pane should be fixed. i.e., If I drag, it should not expand. How can I implement this ?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use a class that you derive from CSplitterWnd. In your derived class handle the mouse messages by doing nothing. I.e., do not call the base class handler, so the CSplitterWnd class will not see the mouse actions.